# Microsecond Sleep in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, delay, sleep

`udelay()`, `mdelay()`, `usleep_range()` all are giving run time errors:

```
symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: __const_udelay
```

I'm trying with [ns3-DCE-linux](https://www.nsnam.org/overview/projects/direct-code-execution/), hence I'm able to see the error but in Linux Kernel, I get a kernel panic.

From [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/delay.h) `udelay()` is defined as a macro.

```
#define udelay(n)                                                \
 ({                                                              \
         if (__builtin_constant_p(n)) {                          \
                 if ((n) / 20000 >= 1)                           \
                          __bad_udelay();                        \
                 else                                            \
                         __const_udelay((n) * 0x10c7ul);         \
         } else {                                                \
                 __udelay(n);                                    \
         }                                                       \
 })
```

From [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/delay.h) `mdelay()` is defined as a macro which uses `udelay()`.

```
#ifndef mdelay
#define mdelay(n) (\
        (__builtin_constant_p(n) && (n)<=MAX_UDELAY_MS) ? udelay((n)*1000) : \
        ({unsigned long __ms=(n); while (__ms--) udelay(1000);}))
#endif
```

`usleep_range()` also uses `udelay()` after a long tracking.

I can clearly see definition of `__const_udelay()` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L115).

```
inline void __const_udelay(unsigned long xloops)
 {
         int d0;

         xloops *= 4;
         asm("mull %%edx"
                 :"=d" (xloops), "=&a" (d0)
                 :"1" (xloops), ""
                 (this_cpu_read(cpu_info.loops_per_jiffy) * (HZ/4)));

         __delay(++xloops);
 }
 EXPORT_SYMBOL(__const_udelay);
```

and included as `extern` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/delay.h#L19).

```
extern void __const_udelay(unsigned long xloops);
```

The only thing working is `msleep()`.

Is there anyway I can give a few microsecond sleep in kernel? (delay or sleep. But sleep is preferable.)

What is the reason of above error? Is this hardware dependent? How to solve the error?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding header file included? `#include <linux/delay.h>`

Comment: Yeah. I tried with `#include <linux/delay.h>` and `#include <asm/delay.h>`, but none of them seem to work.