# Definition of usleep in C

Tags: c, linux

I am looking for the definition of `usleep()`.

I found the declaration in `/usr/include/unistd.h`. But there it's declared as

`extern int usleep (__useconds_t __useconds);`

Where to find the definition of the function?
(Please mention if any way is there other than grep, so that for other library functions also I can follow.)

I'm using gcc version 4.8.3 in Fedora 21 with Linux Kernel 4.1

Comment: What do you mean by "definition"?

Comment: if you're looking for one implementation http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/usleep.c?v=glibc-2.14

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The definition of the function/macro `usleep` which contains the body, I suppose.

Comment: @IsaA Thanks. If it works, that'd help I guess.

Comment: @RatDon Oh, you mean the source code, the implementation. It's going to be a thin wrapper around `nanosleep`, I'd expect.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I thought `nanosleep` and `nano-delay` use high resolution timer and are recommended not to be used with much high values. Aren't they?

Comment: @RatDon: are you coding a user-land program, or some kernel module?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Trying to integrate the user-mode one to the kernel. Both are in `C` only. Right?

Comment: @RatDon: You cannot do this. Read much more about the role of the kernel. See http://kernelnewbies.org/

Answer (score 4):

As with most library functions, you'll find no definition, as it's already compiled in the standard library that is linked automatically to your object modules by the compiler. You can probably find the full sources of your libc in the source packages provided by your Linux distribution, as well as on the glibc site (but keep in mind that some distributions add their patches).

As for `usleep`, you probably won't find anything interesting, [it's just a wrapper around `nanosleep`](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/usleep.c#0024), which in turn is just a syscall (so you'll just find some register setup followed by a `sysenter` instruction - the juicy stuff happens in kernel mode). *edit* actually, as `nanosleep` is a cancellable syscall it's a bit more complicated, but the point stands

Comment: The problem is in kernel mode no micro second sleep is available. But in the user mode `usleep` is there. So I'm trying to integrate the user mode `usleep` to the kernel. No doubt it doesn't give a micro second precision, But something is better than nothing. Thanks. I'll look for it.

Comment: @RatDon: calling `usleep` or `nanosleep` from *kernel* code (e.g. your kernel module) is wrong and meaningless. It is however possible in user-land application programs.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Since there is no kernel function for micro-second sleep, I've to try. Kernel also uses `gcc` for compilation. So worth a try. :-)

Comment: It is much worse than that. You should STFW or ask a new question (or at the very least, edit your question). Notice that the kernel is a freestanding C program, but application code are hosted C programs. **Don't call `usleep` in kernel code**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Already asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264257/microsecond-sleep-in-linux-kernel. I'm simulating the network stack of kernel with ns3-DCE. Since it's a simulation, I guess it'll not have any problem with the user code.